# Why doesn't my map overlay work?

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay

This is my overlay class

```
 public class Overlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    public Overlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));

        }

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem>mOverlays= new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();


    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i); }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {

      return true;
    }

}
```

When I add this overlay as:

In OnCreate-->

```
Overlay overlay=new Overlay (drawable);
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
GeoPoint myGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((mGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()),
                (mGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()));

        OverlayItem mOverlayItem = new OverlayItem(myGeoPoint, "", "");
        overlay.addOverlay(mOverlayItem );
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
```

and get NullPointeException why?
Please give me solution.

Thanks.

Comment: post stacktrace. or better, read it and analyse it yourself. not so hard, you know, just find the line number in your class, follow it, wonder what could be null there, and voila.

Comment: have u set the latitude and longitude ? Post your logcat or tell the line showing null pointer exception.

Comment: yup.. "mGeoPoint" is a geopoint and I already set it.

Comment: I doubt that is working! try to place double lattitude=18.5297 ;
double longitude=73.8491 ; and use this in creating the GeoPoint Object.

Comment: Did you make neccesary changes to your manifest file. Also, did you place your apikey in the mapview in your layout. There could be a lot that could be going wrong here. Can we have the log please?